# No FileIO in Windows Phone?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

In Windows 8 WinRT, there was a convenient class `FileIO` that would let you slurp an IStorageFile into memory in one async call. It's not supported on WP8; is there a counterpart, or should I do this the long way, via a stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FIleIO class isn't available on WP8. Also, most ApplicationData folders aren't supported on WP8. If I remember correctly only LocalFolder and one other ApplicationData folder is supported (either TemporaryFolder or LocalSettings).

ApplicationData.LocalFolder is IsoStore. It's not "equivalent to IsoStore"; it is IsoStore. Files located in IsoStore can now be referenced with "ms-appx://" url schema. On the whole when working with IsoStore on WP it's best to just use the WP7 [IsolatedStorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile%28VS.95%29.aspx) APIs.

However, when coding in C++ you don't have that luxury so you'll have to use ApplicationData.LocalFolder. Also, there's a few places that'll require you work with the WinPRT types and not the C# types, so that's another place you'll have to use ApplicationData.LocalFolder. In those cases, yep, you'll have to use DataWriter and DataReader to read and write.

Comment: `Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder` is working fine for me from WinRT